# 504 Timeout when running 'yo angular-fullstack:openshift'

Tags: timeout, openshift, yeoman, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

I'm new to OpenShift and am trying to follow the MEANStack example [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-example-meanstack.html).

When I run `yo angular-fullstack:openshift myApp` I'm getting the following error...

```
Creating application 'myApp' ... Server returned an unexpected error code: 504

    ✖ { [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c rhc app create myApp nodejs-0.10 mongodb-2.4 -s --noprompt --no-git NODE_ENV=production
    ]
      killed: false,
      code: 1,
      signal: null,
      cmd: '/bin/sh -c rhc app create myApp nodejs-0.10 mongodb-2.4 -s --noprompt --no-git NODE_ENV=production' }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Is there a way to increase the timeout via yeoman/rhc to prevent the 504 coming?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide some more detail on this such as code sample, and the steps you are following in executing the program?

Comment: I haven't written any code yet... I am just trying to set up an OpenShift application with angular-fullstack following this guide...  https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-example-meanstack.html.

Answer (score 0):

I have received this issue a few times and was never able to identify the cause.  I believe it is simply a network or load issue with accessing your first build.  After deleting the failed deployment application and simply retrying I was eventually able to get a successful deployment.